# why is id(1) is id(1) returning False?

Tags: python, object, comparison

I know the `is` operator compares the id of the two, not the value
However when you evaluate id(1) and id(1), the object (which is an int) is equal to one another.

So why is it returning false?

```
id(1) # 27533656
id(1) is id(1) # False
type(id(1)) # int
```

so then, technically, deduce it to

```
id(1) is id(1)
27533656 is 27533656 # has to be True!
```

Comment: What made you think that `27533656 is 27533656 # has to be True!`? They're inevitably *equal*, but that **does not** mean that they must be *identical*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- I think that equality and identity for immutable objects like `int` end up confusing people frequently.  For _mutable_ objects, it's easy to distinguish between equality and identity (mutate one of the references and see of the other changes).  For _immutable_ objects like `int` or `tuple`, the only way to distinguish them is by their `ID`.  This is compounded by the fact that small integer literals, interned strings and some tuples are actually cached by the interpreter so they end up with the same id anyway which makes the rules more complex ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe the console made me think like that, if you wanna know. Copy that line and paste it. see what it spits out

Comment: @taesu "is on my machine" != "has to be." But you're right--if `id(1) is id(1)` were necessarily evaluated identically to `27533656 is 27533656`, and the latter were always evaluated as `True`, that would imply (transitively) that `id(1) is id(1)` would necessarily always be `True`. But in fact `id(1)` is not necessarily going to be the same  as a literal `27533656`, even if `id(1) == 27533656`.

Comment: As @mgilson touches on, this is somewhat complex - the fact that the two literals end up being the same object is not, as far as I'm aware, guaranteed by the specification, and may even vary between an interpreted session and running a script. In general `x == y` (*equality*) should not be confused with `x is y` (*identity*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is` checks for object **identity** whereas `==` checks object **equality**.  The difference can be subtle, but is most easy to see when dealing with mutable objects like lists:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x[:]  # copy, not the same list
x is y  # False
x == y  # True
```

If I add something to `x`, `y` won't see it:

```
x.append(4)
x == y  # now False since they have diverged.
```

But, if I alias `x` and append to it, the alias will also see the changes:

```
z = x  # alias `z` to `x`
x.append(5)
x == z  # True
```

And the reason for this is because `z` *is* `x`.

```
z is x  # True
```

In this case, the `id` of `1` is consistent because CPython<sup>1</sup> caches small integers for efficiency (so the object literal `1` is always the same object -- and therefore the same Id).  However, the return value of `id` can actually be a different instances of `int` that have equivalent values.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is a well known implementation detail for CPython.  Other implementations (and future versions) are free behave differently so do not rely on this behaviour.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You're slightly misinterpreting what the `is` syntax does.

What you are doing with that bit of code is roughly:

```
id(id(1)) == id(id(1))
```

Because the value returned by the `id` function is not static and not guaranteed to be the same identity, they will most likely be different identities.

As proof, when I put those into a print statement I get:

```
print id(id(1)) # 4327028
print id(id(1)) # 4326968
```

Which are obviously not the same.

If you were to change the code to:

```
if 1 is 1: # basically in this case id(1) == id(1)
    print "success"
```

You would find that the values are indeed the same id.

As noted in the comments. The `x is x` and `id(x) == id(x)` methods of determining equivalence are not always the same for all literal types.
In the specific case of this question they may be treated as equal.

Comment: Note, the `1 is 1` thing doesn't work with all literals... `[] is []` ends up being `False`.  A really surprising thing about CPython is that frequently, `id([]) == id([])` will return `True` (with the reason being that when the second list is created, the first one has already been reaped by the garbage collector).

Comment: @mgilson That's pretty cool. Extremely weird when I've been using `C` so much, but a nice bit of knowledge there. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I thought because `print id(1); print id(1)`  yielded same result, that they would evaluate to true on `is` how come `print id(1); print id(1)` is identical but `print id(id(1)); print id(id(1))` isn't

Comment: @taesu When you say "`print id(1); print id(1)` is identical", what you're saying is "I'm looking at the output and I see the same number." This is ***not*** the same as the *objects* being identical, which is the point of this answer.